# Projector for generalized two-state system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, observables

For a two-state quantum system I can write a observable in terms of Pauli matrices in the form

$$A=\hat{a} \cdot \vec{\sigma}, $$

where $\hat{a}$ is an unit vector. And I can write the projector as

$$\Pi_a=\frac{\mathbb{I}+\lambda(\hat{a}\cdot\vec{\sigma}) }{2}$$

Where $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity operator, and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, taking values in $\{-1,1\}$.

Tthe operator $A$ can be written in the spectral decomposition as: $A=\sum \limits_{\lambda} \lambda \Pi_a$

My ***question*** is: How can I obtain the projector in the same form for a generalized observable written now as $$A=a_0\mathbb{I}+ \vec{a}\cdot \vec{\sigma}$$
(if it it is possible to write a projector in this case)?

I thought it could be in the form of

$$\Pi_a=\frac{\lambda(a_0\mathbb{I}+\hat{a}\cdot\vec{\sigma}) }{2}$$

but that is not a projector, because it does not follows the completeness relation, even though, if I sum over $\lambda$ over I get back operator $A$.

Comment: Random typesetting observation: `\cdot` ($\cdot$) isn't a great representation of the inner product operator, but it is a lot better than just using a period ($.$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the identity to your observable does not change the eigenvectors at all; it merely shifts both associated eigenvalues by a constant.  So the operators
$$P_{A}=\frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{I}\pm\hat{a}\cdot\vec{\sigma})$$ still project out the eigenvectors of $A$.

Comment: It make sense. Because I am not making any rotation or internal transformation to the eigenvectors. Only translanting by a factor of $a_0$ the observable. So it eigenvalues also translate it, but not the eigenvectors.